# How to export movie from Powerpoint 2010?

Tags: c#, video, export, powerpoint

How to export embedded video from powerpoint 2010 to external file programmatically using MS Office PIA (Primary Interop Assemblies) or other ways?
Embedding video in presentation is a new feature in Powerpoint 2010 and  I Can't find solution for this.

Comment: I think best answer here is the following because it works universally (all Windows versions, Linux, OS X) for both ppt and pptx https://stackoverflow.com/a/36516175/54964

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PPTX files are just compressed archives. The embedded video should be stored within it somewhere, possibly under the media folder but I'm not sure.

You can use something like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to extract the media and save to where you like.

Note this means you don't need to use PIAs at all which is preferable if you're doing this on a server for instance.

Comment: Thank you. I just unpack pptx file and found all embedded movies inside files. I will just unpack file and will look for unpacked movies. Thx

Comment: Happy to help, don't forget to mark the answer if its correct for you.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Make sure all files in your PC display file extension names (as filename.pptx, filename.exe, etc.). If not, enable them:

1. Go into Windows Explorer

   If you don't have a toolbar or shortcut (usually a file folder with a magnifying glass superimposed over it) to get there, you can:

   1. Go to the Start menu
   2. Select Run
   3. Type "explorer.exe" in the box
   4. Hit the Enter key
2. In Windows Explorer, choose Folder Options from the Tools menu
3. Click on the View tab
4. Find "Hide File Extensions for Known File Types" and UNcheck its box.

Step 2: Highlight the PowerPoint file, click “F2” (or right click and select "Rename") and change the name of the presentation by adding a .zip to the end. (e.g. filename.pptx.zip).

Step 3: Click “Yes” if the following dialog box appears after changing the name.
Step 4: Unzip the file and open it. You can find a “ppt” folder in it. Open the “media” folder in “ppt” folder, you will find all the movies inserted into PowerPoint.

Comment: Wouldn't "Right click on file -> 'Open With ...'" and select WinZip or similar be considerably easier? Also, the OP wanted to do this programmatically using C#.

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows/Linux/Mac, it works similar:

1. Copy your ppt (to be sure not to damage your original);
2. Change name by adding .zip;
3. Are you sure? Yes you are;
4. Zip is creating a folder from your file which you can easily access;
5. Find folder Ppt and within folder Media;
6. Files are in order of extention, most videos are grouped together.
7. That's all.

Comment: This is the best answer here, and work universally (Windows, Linux, OS X) with both ppt and pptx.