# C#/Powerpoint add-in file select and "store"

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in, powerpoint

For one part of the add-in I am creating I would like to add a video file. I am not necessarily trying to show the video in powerpoint, but I need to place this file somewhere for later reference.

So a) can I store the file within the powerpoint file, or b) if I have a relatively positioned file (same folder) could I then access the file easily?

I will be getting the file name from file open dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed the you could use the following code to add a new shape containing the video and hide it.

```
Dim shape As shape
Set shape = Slide.Shapes.AddMediaObject(videofile, 0, 0, -1, -1)
shape.Visible = msoFalse
```

However, it can be tricky to retrieve the video file later. See [How to export movie from Powerpoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091628/how-to-export-movie-from-powerpoint-2010) and [VBA Export embedded video from Powerpoint presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773999/vba-export-embedded-video-from-powerpoint-presentation).

Or you could read the video data and store it in a slide or shape tag which might be an overkill depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Surely, you could copy the video file to the same directory as the PPT file but it will be lost if you move the PPT file or send it by mail etc.

Comment: Embedding the video as Paul B. describes would be simplest and probably best, but will only work in PowerPoint 2010.  Earlier versions can't embed videos.  PowerPoint 2007 with SP2 can play embedded videos from 2010 but earlier versions can't do even that. Linking ... If you put the video file in the same directory as the saved PPT and LINK to just the filename, not the path, the link will not usuall break when you move the file elsewhere, so long as the video and PPT stay together in the same directory.

Comment: Mea culpa, AddMediaObject only links video files. You will need to use `Shapes.AddMediaObject2(videofile, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1)` which is only available in PPT 2010 as Steve pointed out.